# scene is gray color and skybox disappear on unity game engine

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my project scenen window look like gray or black, but game window is normal！ Please help me! Thank you!
ps:The same as create new project!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! This community is specifically for helping with coding related questions. You will probably have better luck asking for help from the Unity 3D community (e.g. https://answers.unity.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the Scene window there is a little button, looks like a series of 'layers' with a plus sign. There's a down facing arrow to the right of this. Click that and you should see a load of checkboxes. Click the one that says 'Skybox' - that'll turn it back on again.

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!  Is icon like book and star！

Answer (score 0):

Disable PostProcesing by uncheck it

[image]

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.